# Temperature Gradient

Tags: thermodynamics

While writing the Fouriers Equation of Heat Transfer, some textbooks write the Temperature Gradient in terms of partial derivative while some other write it in terms of total derivative?

What is the difference between these two? Is there some kind of a difference during their application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that in one case the textbook might have considered a multi-dimensional problem (partiale derivatives), while in the other case a uni-dimensional problem (total derivative).